# What is the right way to send data between modules in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

One of the great things about angular is that you can have independent Modules that you can reuse in different places. Say that you have a module to paint, order, and do a lot of things with lists. Say that this module will be used all around your application. And finally, say that you want to populate it in different ways. Here is an example:

```js
angular.module('list', []).controller('listController', ListController);
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['list']).controller('appController', AppController);

function AppController() {
  this.name = "Misae";
  this.fetch = function() {
    console.log("feching");
    //change ListController list
    //do something else
  }
}

function ListController() {
  this.list = [1, 2, 3];
  this.revert = function() {
    this.list.reverse();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="app" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="appController as App">

  <div class="filters">
    Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="App.name" />
    <button ng-click="App.fetch()">Fetch</button>
  </div>

  <div class="list" ng-controller="listController as List">
    <button ng-click="List.revert()">Revert</button>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in List.list">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Now, when you click on Fetch button, you'll send the name (and other filters and stuff) to an API using `$http` and so on. Then you get some data, including a list of items you want to paint. Then you want to send that list to the `List` module, to be painted.

It has to be this way because you'll be using the list module in diferent places and it will always paint a list and add some features like reordering and reversing it. While the filters and the API connection will change, your list behaviour will not, so there must be 2 different modules.

That said, what is the best way to send the data to the List module after fetching it? With a Service?

Comment: are you up to use angularjs 1.5.x?

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro Could be... but I'd like to know a compatible way as well

Comment: From what you said, the proper solution would be using components instead of controllers, and in a compatible way without components would be directives

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro is right - components are the best solution for your task

Comment: @Dennis yes I am (but not just me). Controllers don't have a built-in way to comunicate with each others (they were not made for this anyway) and directives are an overkill for the task. Therefore angularjs's team have introduced the components, which brings some benefits for reusability and stuff. It can be done with directives as well, but is much less fancy than compoenets. Cheers :{D

Comment: If 2 modules have the need to transfer data between each other (2 ways data transfer) you should merge them into one. The need for module data-transfering usually come from bad design. For different features like you mentioned, consider using components rather than splitting into different modules

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be using [Angular components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) for this task.

You should create a module with a component that will be displaying lists and providing some actions that will modify the list and tell the parent to update the value.

```
var list = angular.module('listModule', []);

list.controller('listCtrl', function() {
    this.reverse = function() {
        this.items = [].concat(this.items).reverse();
        this.onUpdate({ newValue: this.items });
    };
});

list.component('list', {
  bindings: {
    items: '<',
    onUpdate: '&'
  },
  controller: 'listCtrl',
  template: '<button ng-click="$ctrl.reverse()">Revert</button><ul><li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items">{{ item }}</li></ul>'
});
```

This way when you click on "Revert" `list` component will reverse the array and execute the function provided in `on-update` attribute of HTML element.

Then you can simply set your app to be dependent on this module

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['listModule']);
```

and use `list` component

```
<list data-items="list" data-on-update="updateList(newValue)"></list>
```

You can see the rest of the code in [the example](https://jsfiddle.net/8pqtvhen/8/)

Answer (score 4):

It is very simple. Please take a look at this small snippet. comments are added to highlight.

You can have a **common module** that contains all the data that needs to be shared across modules by two steps

- adding module dependency
- injecting corresponding provider in the respective module's controller

```js
angular.module('commonAppData', []).factory('AppData',function(){
var a,b,c;
  a=1;
  return{
    a:a,
    b:b,
    c:c
  }
})

angular.module('list', ['commonAppData']).controller('listController', ListController);
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['list','commonAppData']).controller('appController', AppController);

function AppController(AppData) {
  //assigning a variable
  AppData.a=100;
  
  this.name = "Misae";
  this.fetch = function() {
    console.log("feching");
    //change ListController list
    //do something else
  }
}

function ListController(AppData) {
  //Using the data sent by App Controller
  this.variableA=AppData.a;
  
  this.list = [1, 2, 3];
  this.revert = function() {
    this.list.reverse();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="app" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="appController as App">

  <div class="filters">
    Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="App.name" />
    <button ng-click="App.fetch()">Fetch</button>
  </div>

  <div class="list" ng-controller="listController as List">
    <b>Shared variable : {{List.variableA}}</b>
    <br>
    <button ng-click="List.revert()">Revert</button>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in List.list">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why would anyone upvote this answer? Firstly, it doesnt solve the problem with List reusability. All you did is introduced another layer between the List and App controllers to share data. Meanwhile, it doesn't solve the problem of passing lists to rendering layer because the data is hardcoded in ListController. Secondly, it is not the solution anyone would want to be using in production because you will run into problems as soon as you will need to dynamically include list rendering in your directives/components.

Comment: I hope the question is related to sharing data between modules but no where it is specified directives/ components are involved. Why is a Common Service to hold the data required for the application not a solution?

Comment: Citing OP - "Say that you have a module to paint, order, and do a lot of things with lists. Say that this module will be used all around your application." Now think about your solution in environment when you have 10 lists with 10 different data sets. How will you achieve that with your current code?

Comment: Firstly All the 10 lists with 10 different data sets will not be shared across modules.The data that are to be shared is assigned to corresponding variables in a provider in common module. Those modules which looks for a shared data will be having this common module dependency and corresponding provider.
Secondly, Can you tell me what is the best practice for injecting same modules dependency.

Comment: How will you solve this? Suggest a **best practice**? I have modules as student, teacher, school, management and so on. All these modules needs routing and so they are dependent on 'ui-router' and many modules like **ngResource**,**ngAnimate** and so on. **Answer this!!\**

Comment: Okay, now I'm almost sure you misunderstood the problem OP was asking a solution to. Citing again - "what is the best way to send the data to the List module after fetching it?". Obviously OP is asking for a way to pass the data that will be rendered as a list, not some data shared between multiple instances of list component.

Comment: Yes. the entire list object can be assigned and shared as I said. Please have a look at Angular Best Practices. **There is no answer for my question**

Comment: Okay, now I see that you either don't want to or can't understand the points I was trying to make. I don't want to spend my time trying to reason someone that is not willing to cooperate. Good luck!

Comment: Just tell me one thing. The solution that I provided will not work! I can understand what you are saying. Just for the sake of sharing data, why to **create a component**?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways to handle objects acress multiple controllers. Here are two.

**1. Using Angulars `$rootScope`**

You can assign an object to `$rootScope`which will hold up all information. This object can be passed into every controller through Angulars dependency injection. Also you can listen up to changes on your object by watching it through `$watch` or `$emit`.

Using `$rootScope` is an easy way, but may lead to performance issues on larger applications.

**2. Using services**

Angular provides a possibility to share object through services. Instead of defining your object inside of your controller, you could also do that inside of a service. Doing so you could inject that service into any controller and use it's values across your application.

```
function AppController(listService) {
  // reference to the injected data
}

function ListController(listService) {
  // update data
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to pass data from one module to another module and many ppl have suggested different ways.

One of the finest way and cleaner approach is using a `factory` instead of polluting `$rootScope or using $emit or $broadcast or $controller`.If you want to know more about how to use all of this visit this [blog](https://ngcoderscope.wordpress.com/2016/08/09/accessing-methods-from-one-controller-to-another-in-angular-js/) on 
**Accessing functions of one controller from another in angular js**

By simply inject the factory you have created in main module and add child modules as dependancy in main module, then inject factory in child modules to access the factory objects.

Here is a sample [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5I4FhdpPnq5Dpv3mlbh?p=preview) on how to use **factory** for sharing data across the application.

Lets create a factory which can be used in entire application across all controllers to store data and access them.

Advantages with factory is you can create objects in it and intialise them any where in the controllers or we can set the defult values by intialising them in the factory itself.

**Factory**

```
app.factory('SharedData',['$http','$rootScope',function($http,$rootScope){

    var SharedData = {}; // create factory object...
    SharedData.appName ='My App';
    return SharedData;
}]);
```

**Service**

```
app.service('Auth', ['$http', '$q', 'SharedData', function($http, $q,SharedData) {
   this.getUser = function() {

            return $http.get('user.json')
              .then(function(response) {
                  this.user = response.data;
                  SharedData.userData = this.user; // inject in the service and create a object in factory ob ject to store user data..
                  return response.data;
              }, function(error) {
                  return $q.reject(error.data);
              });

    };

}]);
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("testController", ["$scope",'SharedData','Auth',
  function($scope,SharedData,Auth) {

    $scope.user ={};
   // do a service call via service and check the shared data which is factory object ...
   var user = Auth.getUser().then(function(res){
       console.log(SharedData);
       $scope.user = SharedData.userData;// assigning to scope.
   });


  }]);
```

**In HTML**

```
<body ng-app='app'>
    <div class="media-list" ng-controller="testController">

       <pre> {{user | json}}</pre>

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS provides `$on`, `$emit`, and `$broadcast` services for event-based communication between controllers.

So, if we want to pass data from the inner controller (**`listController`**) to outer controller (**`appController`**) then we have to use `$emit`. It dispatches an event name upwards through the scope hierarchy and notify to the registered `$rootScope`.

**Working Plunker :** https://plnkr.co/edit/szf9jHvvOPLOvQc5sQI2?p=preview

This plunker is not as per the exact requirement as I don't know the API response but this sample plunker describe the problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the circumstance. Is there a parent child relationship? Is the relationship unknown, or you simply want to avoid having to worry about it at all?

I think this post lays it out well (it always seems to be helpful):

http://mean.expert/2016/05/21/angular-2-component-communication/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the publisher-subscriber pattern implemented in $rootScope.

In the ListController you have to inject $rootScope and after that you have to subscribe to an arbitrary called event that could have the pattern _data_received

```
$rootScope.$on('ingredients_data_received', function(ingredients) { prepare_recipe();});
```

so in your AppController you have to call $rootScope.$emit once the data of that list has been received

```
$rootScope.$emit('ingredients_data_received', ingredients);
```

This is just a way to pass data, you can also push those data or the promise in a $rootScope property but this is not a good practice, or you can create your own Service that manage the data for you (remember that you are working with a frontend framework so the controller has to control the view, the business logic has to be transfered to a service, not to a crontroller).

Comment: Please don't do this and use a service instead.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use angular resource with a caching layer to persist data to multiple controllers using a singular method. This has a few benefits namely any controller has the same entry point to data. Keep in mind sometimes you need to fetch fresh data when navigating from one portion of the site to another so persisting http data is not always ideal.

```
'use strict';
(function() {
    angular.module('customModule')
        .service('BookService', BookService);

    BookService.$inject = ['$resource'];

    function BookService($resource) {
        var BookResource = $resource('/books', {id: '@id'}, {
            getBooks: {
                method: 'GET',
                cache: true
            }
        });

        return {
            getBooks: getBooks
        };

        function getBooks(params) {
            if (!params) {
                params = {};
            }
            return BookResource.getBooks(params).$promise;
        }
    }
})();
```

In any controller

```
BookService.getBooks().then(function(books) {
    //books will be cached so invoking the call will return the same set of data anywhere
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Services` in angular are used to share functionality between components. Please try to keep them simple and with a single responsibility/purpose.
An idea would be creating a `store` service that will cache every response from the api in your application. Then you don't have to request it every time.

Hope it helps! ;)